# NancyFx, implementing themes support for a view engine

Tags: nancy

As I didn't find anything useful googlin' for it, so I decided to ask it here.
How easy/quick is it to implement UI themes support for a view engine in NancyFx?

A code example would be really appreciated.

Comment: At what capacity do you want to do this? Load different views all entirely? Or just style sheets?

Comment: Well, ideally, the aim is to load different views not just style sheets. As far as I understand, implementing themes based only on style sheets should be an easy exercise. To add overriden views per theme would be more interesting. (e.g. views for Bootstap theme might have different html markup then views for a theme that uses OOCSS to define layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can setup custom View Location Conventions https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/View-location-conventions. In the conventions you have access to the entire NancyContext. So you could perhaps add something to NancyContext.Items and look at that in the convention, or if this is for authenticated users you could add a property to your IUserIdentity implementation (which you get to using NancyContext.CurrentUser) and use that.